# Laptop seems to have more than 2 channels but alsamixer doesn't show them

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

My HP Envy 13 is using a HD Realtek sound device. In Linux, it's using the ALC295 driver.

Sound works out of the box, but didn't sound as full as it had on Windows. Here's aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Seems fairly standard, except that 'speaker-test -c 6' (which plays the sound on Front Left, Center, Front Right, Rear Right, Rear Left, and LFE in that order) sounds like it's playing sound through 5 different speakers. LFE has no sound, Rear Right and Rear Left are much softer.

Marketting material from this laptop (and my ears) say that there's quad speakers in it. How can I get multi-channel audio playing from this laptop via alsa or pulseaudio?

Comment: I know nothing about all this, but I have seen in other answers that you may be able to switch hardware "profiles" with the pavucontrol gui, Configuration tab.

Comment: Yeah I know about pulseaudio profiles but in this case there's only Analog Stereo Out and a bunch of HDMI options. Pulseaudio's surround sound is fairly restricted and alsa-reliant, as far as I can tell, hence my question focusing on Alsa.